# “HTML1509 unmatched end tag” warning in Edge

Tags: html

I get “HTML1509 unmatched end tag” warning in Edge browser. Is it something to worry about or just disregard as non-issue?

I’ve read online that it’s just MS browsers are being to fussy about little things…

[I get a warning on this page](https://apostasia.ru/ru/kupit-knigu)

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: It's HTML coding question, I guess...

Comment: Can you post the code causing the error?

Comment: I have no idea... It's just on the page I provided in my question